# Problem with displaying List by jsp in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

Hi i have a problem with my project,That's my posts.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blog Site-posts</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th>Written by</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="Post">
                <tr>
                    <td>${Post.postId}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="${post.postDate}" /></td>
                    <td>${Post.text}</td>
                    <td>${Post.authorId}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's my PostController

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/posts",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPosts(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts",postService.findall());
        return "posts";
    }
}
```

and that is my post class

```
public class Post {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int postId;

    //@Column(unique=true)
    //@NotEmpty
    private String title;
    //@Column(length=20000)
    @Size(max=20000, message="Message cannot be longer than 20000 characters!")
    //@NotEmpty
    private String text;
    private Date postDate;
    private int authorId;
```

I want to display elements of List with posts in jsp to see how it works , but it looks like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QcoJ.png)

What's wrong with jsp or controller?

Comment: There is nothing bound to the c: or fmt: namespaces (or you haven't added yuor full JSP). Or there simply is no data to show.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to  `posts.jsp` before tag `html` :

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```